# Can I render faster in cycles with a Radeon R5 graphics card?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have a Windows 10 PC with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics 2.00 GHz, Is there support for it to improve Blender Cycles'rendering using GPU? Thanks

Comment: DarkChannel69, welcome to the site. You might want to take the [tour](http://www.blender.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the contents of the [help center](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help). I am flagging your question for migration to the [Hardware recommendations](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site, because it is out of scope for Blender stack exchange, since it is about Hardware, and not about using Blender as defined in the help center.

Answer (score 2):

I have experience with an R5, although I'm on a *really* crappy laptop here.

In my experience, OpenCL support for Cycles isn't that good. Slow, limited(no support for HDR textures, volumetrics, SSS), and the architecture still is pretty crappy. My AMD A8 usually does just fine for all rendering tasks. Then again, I'm on a crappy 4GB RAM computer, so test your setup.

In short, there is support. It is not guaranteed to actually be of assistance. Get a Nvidia if possible.

Comment: I agree with LiquidHelix. Go with NVidia whenever possible because of the CUDA supported features. I am using R9 290 and sometimes it gets really frustrating to blender certain scenes.