# Cycles gpu rendering opencl freezing

Tags: gpu, opencl

I have been learning blender for the past month and today i have found out how to enable GPU rendering but when switching from CPU to GPU compute my computer freezes. here are my specs:
CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo E8400 3.00 GHz
GPU: AMD R5 230 (not m)

Comment: Start blender from system console.  Is anything printed to console on GPU render?

Comment: support for older (in general) AMD cards is weak, and a new, faster, multicore CPU could be even faster that your GPU, with almost no ram limits... see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49071/can-i-render-faster-in-cycles-with-a-radeon-r5-graphics-card